# Android : Fragment doesn't fit into Fragment Container

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-constraintlayout, android-framelayout

I have a Fragment Container View inside MainActivity. And I have a register fragment. Inside the register fragment, I have Constraint layout.When I am starting app in my phone, register fragment doesn't fit into Fragment Container. How can I solve this problem?

---

[ScreenShoot from my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfzeN.jpg)

---

My MainActivity.xml code

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textSize="64dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
        android:textColor="@color/siyah"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/fragmentcontainerview_tasarimi"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_margin="22dp"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"
        android:elevation="20dp"
        android:stateListAnimator="@null"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

My Register Fragment xml code

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".RegisterEkrani"
    android:background="@drawable/arkaplatform"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/registerekrani_main_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
            android:text="Register"
            android:textColor="@color/siyah"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>


        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/registerekrani_isim_edittext"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="22dp"
            android:hint="İsmin"
            android:textColorHint="@color/turuncu"
            app:boxStrokeColor="@color/turuncu"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/registerekrani_main_text">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/registerekrani_username_edittext"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="22dp"
            android:hint="Kullanıcı Adın"
            android:textColorHint="@color/turuncu"
            app:boxStrokeColor="@color/turuncu"
            app:helperTextTextColor="@color/siyah"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/registerekrani_isim_edittext">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/registerekrani_mail_edittext"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="22dp"
            android:hint="Mail adresin"
            android:textColorHint="@color/turuncu"
            app:boxStrokeColor="@color/turuncu"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/registerekrani_username_edittext">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"/>

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/registerekrani_sifren_edittext"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="22dp"
            android:hint="Şifren"
            android:textColorHint="@color/turuncu"
            app:boxStrokeColor="@color/turuncu"
            app:helperTextTextColor="@color/siyah"
            app:endIconMode="password_toggle"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/registerekrani_mail_edittext">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"/>

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/register_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buton_tasarim"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            android:paddingStart="20dp"
            android:paddingEnd="20dp"
            android:stateListAnimator="@null"
            android:text="Register"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/register_iptal"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/registerekrani_sifren_edittext" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/register_iptal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:letterSpacing="0.10"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Geri"
            android:textColor="@color/siyah"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/register_button"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/registerekrani_sifren_edittext" />



    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: It is possible for a layout to exceed its bounds even if the height is specified as _match_parent_. Within the _ConstraintLayout_, the height of each view (usually `wrap_content` + top margins + bottom margins may be larger than what is possible on the screen. In this case, every layout will exceed the boundaries. There are a few ways to address this. Add a scrollview as @che10 suggests, shrink the vertical margins or place all the views within a vertical view chain that is constrained to the top and bottom of the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The register Fragment fits perfectly fine, it is fitting according to the area available to it, in the Fragment Container. Since the area is limited, so that is why to you it seems it is being cut off.

Here is what you can do, you can add a ScrollView in your RegisterFragment, I have no idea why you are using a FrameLayout, but you would be fine replacing it with a ScrollView as far as I know. Beside that you will need to give bottom constraint to your last element and a margin from Bottom. Here is how it will be then.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".RegisterEkrani"
    android:background="@drawable/arkaplatform"
    >

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/registerekrani_main_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
            android:text="Register"
            android:textColor="@color/siyah"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>


        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/registerekrani_isim_edittext"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="22dp"
            android:hint="İsmin"
            android:textColorHint="@color/turuncu"
            app:boxStrokeColor="@color/turuncu"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/registerekrani_main_text">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/registerekrani_username_edittext"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="22dp"
            android:hint="Kullanıcı Adın"
            android:textColorHint="@color/turuncu"
            app:boxStrokeColor="@color/turuncu"
            app:helperTextTextColor="@color/siyah"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/registerekrani_isim_edittext">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/registerekrani_mail_edittext"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="22dp"
            android:hint="Mail adresin"
            android:textColorHint="@color/turuncu"
            app:boxStrokeColor="@color/turuncu"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/registerekrani_username_edittext">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"/>

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/registerekrani_sifren_edittext"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="22dp"
            android:hint="Şifren"
            android:textColorHint="@color/turuncu"
            app:boxStrokeColor="@color/turuncu"
            app:helperTextTextColor="@color/siyah"
            app:endIconMode="password_toggle"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/registerekrani_mail_edittext">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"/>

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/register_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/buton_tasarim"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            android:paddingStart="20dp"
            android:paddingEnd="20dp"
            android:stateListAnimator="@null"
            android:text="Register"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/register_iptal"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/registerekrani_sifren_edittext" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/register_iptal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:letterSpacing="0.10"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Geri"
            android:textColor="@color/siyah"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/register_button"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/registerekrani_sifren_edittext" />



    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I am using Navgraph. So ı am using the frame layout.

Comment: Okay, I deleted the FrameLayout and used just ConstraintLayout. But still not fit perfect. How can I resize for screen? Why ConstraintLayout doesn't do this?

Comment: Constraint layout is resizing for your screen @msy, if you see the width is getting adjusted according to the screen size available.
As I suggested you need to user ScrollView. So the portion off the screen can be accessed.

Comment: @msy Just try copying the changes I have made and running it and if that works for you, you can mark the answer as correct.